# Does Tensorflow's QueueBase.enqueue_many preserve order across threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, tensorflow

Let's say two threads are simultaneously trying to enqueue N tensors each, into an instance of a FIFOQueue. I.e., they're calling

`queue_instance.enqueue_many(T)` where `T` is a list of tensors of length `N`.

Let's label each tensor from the first thread as `T1_1` to `T1_N`, and `T2_1` to `T2_N` for the second thread. When all is said and done (both calls to `enqueue_many` have completed), will the order be preserved? I.e., will the queue contain either `[T1_1, ..., T1_N, T2_1, ..., T2_N]` or `[T2_1, ..., T2_N, T1_1, ..., T1_N]`? Or could the tensors be enqueued in an interleaved manner, i.e., `[T2_1, T2_2, T1_1, T2_3, T1_2, ...]`? Or, I suppose, a third option is that there is no rhyme or reason whatsoever: the tensors are enqueued in an arbitrary order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order within the batches enqueued by each thread is preserved. Another way of putting this is that [`FIFOQueue.enqueue_many()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#QueueBase.enqueue_many) executes atomically* with respect to other enqueue operations on the same queue.

---

* However, if the remaining capacity of the queue is less than the size of the batch being enqueued, it is possible to *dequeue* elements from the batch before the enqueue completes—i.e. you are able to enqueue batches that are *larger* than the capacity of the queue, and the enqueue op will block until enough elements have been dequeued.